# need help with postgresql regexp_replace

Tags: regex, postgresql

I need to get rid of trailing repeating non_alphanumeric symbols like

`"thanks ! !!!!!!!"` to `"thanks !"`

If these different symbols then they are ignored.

I quite new to regex,
so I came up with

```
regexp_replace('Thanks . . . .  ', '((\\W)\\s*)(\\2\\s*)+', '\\2')
```

to try it out.

However i realise the trailing space after 'thanks' causes some problem. I would get back `"thanks "` instead of `"thanks ."` This is kinda strange because I used an online regex tool and the first whitespace was not matched. Can anyone help?

note: I did insert the double backslash.

Comment: You want to get rid of all non-alphanumeric symbols except the last one (the punctuation) or actually get rid of every one of them? Or maybe get rid of repeated punctuation? I'm not sure I understand which one you want.

Comment: actually I want to reduce 2 or more repeating, similar symbols (with or without white space) to just 1. for instance ". ... . ." to just "." stuff like "#%@" will remain the same.

Comment: How should spaces be dealt with (since it's not alphanumeric)? If you have the string `"Thanks !!!! ???"` do you want `"Thanks !?"` or `"Thanks ! ?"`? Edit: Line break in a bad place, basically if the original string has spaces between repeated different symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
(\W)(\s*\1)+
```

with

```
\1
```

I don't know PostgreSQL, but from your example, I'm guessing:

```
regexp_replace('Thanks . . . .  ', '(\\W)(\\s*\\1)+', '\\1')
```

This will also replace leading multiple spaces with a single space. If you don't want that (i. e. if you want leading spaces to be left alone entirely), then use

```
([^\s\w])(\s*\1)+   // '([^\\s\\w])(\\s*\\1)+'
```

instead.

Comment: That's how I would do it, too (except I would add another `\s*` to the end to take care of trailing whitespace).  But the OP's regex should work--it works fine in RegexBuddy in "Tcl ARE/PostgreSQL" mode.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
select regexp_replace('Thanks ! !!!!!!!!', '(\\s*)((\\W)\\s*)(\\2\\s*)+', '\\1\\2');
```

result:

```
Thanks !
```